# Is there a font picker on iPhone?

Tags: iphone

as topic, I am strange that why does the SDK not provide API to show the UIFont picker ? like the date Picker......

or maybe some open source code is available now ?

Thanks for your help !

Regards

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I whipped something up in a few minutes which might be what you want: http://github.com/alexrepty/ARFontChooser

Answer (score 6):

I am not aware of existing solutions but you can easily retrieve all font names available in system:

```
for (NSString* familyName in [UIFont familyNames])
     for (NSString* fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName])
         // Store font names or do whatever you want
         // You can create font object using 
         // [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:fontSize];
```

And then allow user to pick one of then in your own font picker with the design you want.